# Problems with a JPA query

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a problem when performing a query in an HQL.

ORM

---

Persona

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "persona")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DynamicUpdate

@SelectBeforeUpdate(value = false)

@SelectBeforeUpdate(value = false)
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "PersonasByRfc", query = "FROM Persona p WHERE p.rfc = :rfc "),
    @NamedQuery(name = "PersonasPorTipoPersona", query = "FROM Persona p WHERE p.tipoPersona = :tipoPersona "),
    @NamedQuery(name = "PersonaByClienteId", query = " SELECT c.persona FROM Cliente c WHERE c.clienteId = :clienteId "),
    @NamedQuery(name = "PersonaMoralActiva", query = "SELECT c.persona FROM Cliente c WHERE c.persona.regimenFiscal = 'MORAL' AND c.estatus = 'ACTIVO' ")
})

public class Persona extends CommonBusinessProperties {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2846894501470704239L;
private Long           personaId;
private CatTipoPersona tipoPersona;
private String         descripcionTipoPersona;
private String         nombres;
private String         apellidoMaterno;
private String         apellidoPaterno;
private RegimenFiscal  regimenFiscal;
private Nacionalidad   nacionalidad;
private String         rfc;
private String         curp;
private Genero         genero;
private Date           fechaNacimiento;
private Boolean        esCliente;
private Boolean        esContratante;
private Boolean        esPagador;
private Boolean        esMontoPagar;
private BigDecimal     montoPagar;
private Boolean        esPorcentajePagar;
private String         porcentajePagar;
private String         origenPersona;
private String         parentesco;
private Parentesco     tranParentesco;
private Cliente        cliente;

private ExpedientePersona expedientePersona;
private List<Domicilio> domicilios = new ArrayList<>(0);
private List<Telefono>  telefonos  = new ArrayList<>(0);
private List<Correo>    correos    = new ArrayList<>(0);

/**
 * Constructor <br>
 * Crea una nueva instancia de Persona. <br>
 *
 * @author Orlando Adrián Ramos Galván (oramos@legosoft.com.mx, orlandoa.ramos@outlook.com)<br>
 */
public Persona() {
    super();
}

/**
 * Constructor <br>
 * Crea una nueva instancia de Persona. <br>
 *
 * @param personaId
 * @author Orlando Adrián Ramos Galván (oramos@legosoft.com.mx, orlandoa.ramos@outlook.com)<br>
 */
public Persona(Long personaId) {
    super();
    this.personaId = personaId;
}

/**
 * Constructor <br>
 * Crea una nueva instancia de Persona. <br>
 *
 * @param personaBuilder
 * @author Orlando Adrián Ramos Galván (oramos@legosoft.com.mx, orlandoa.ramos@outlook.com)<br>
 */
public Persona(PersonaBuilder personaBuilder) {
    this.tipoPersona = personaBuilder.getTipoPersona();
    this.descripcionTipoPersona = personaBuilder.getDescripcionTipoPersona();
    this.nombres = personaBuilder.getNombresORazonSocial();
    this.apellidoMaterno = personaBuilder.getApellidoMaterno();
    this.apellidoPaterno = personaBuilder.getApellidoPaterno();
    this.setRegimenFiscal(personaBuilder.getRegimenFiscal());
    this.setNacionalidad(personaBuilder.getNacionalidad());
    this.setRfc(personaBuilder.getRfc());
    this.curp = personaBuilder.getCurp();
    this.genero = personaBuilder.getGenero();
    this.fechaNacimiento = personaBuilder.getFechaNacimiento();
    this.esCliente = personaBuilder.getEsCliente();
    this.esContratante = personaBuilder.getEsContratante();
    this.esPagador = personaBuilder.getEsPagador();
    this.esMontoPagar = personaBuilder.getEsMontoPagar();
    this.montoPagar = personaBuilder.getMontoPagar();
    this.esPorcentajePagar = personaBuilder.getEsPorcentajePagar();
    this.porcentajePagar = personaBuilder.getPorcentajePagar();
    this.domicilios = personaBuilder.getDomicilios();
    this.telefonos = personaBuilder.getTelefonos();
    this.correos = personaBuilder.getCorreos();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "persona_id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
public Long getPersonaId() {
    return this.personaId;
}

public void setPersonaId(Long personaId) {
    this.personaId = personaId;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity = CatTipoPersona.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "tipo_persona_id")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public CatTipoPersona getTipoPersona() {
    return this.tipoPersona;
}

public void setTipoPersona(CatTipoPersona tipoPersona) {
    this.tipoPersona = tipoPersona;
}

@Column(name = "tipo_persona", length = 50)
public String getDescripcionTipoPersona() {
    return this.descripcionTipoPersona;
}

public void setDescripcionTipoPersona(String tipoPersona) {
    this.descripcionTipoPersona = tipoPersona;
}

@Column(name = "origen_persona", length = 50)
public String getOrigenPersona() {
    return this.origenPersona;

}

@Column(name = "nombres", length = 100)
public String getNombresORazonSocial() {
    return this.nombres;
}

public void setNombresORazonSocial(String nombres) {
    this.nombres = nombres;
}

@Column(name = "apellido_materno", length = 100)
public String getApellidoMaterno() {
    return this.apellidoMaterno;
}

public void setApellidoMaterno(String apellidoMaterno) {
    this.apellidoMaterno = apellidoMaterno;
}

@Column(name = "apellido_paterno", length = 100)
public String getApellidoPaterno() {
    return this.apellidoPaterno;
}

public void setApellidoPaterno(String apellidoPaterno) {
    this.apellidoPaterno = apellidoPaterno;
}

@Transient
public String getNombreCompleto() {
    return this.nombres + " " + this.apellidoMaterno + " " + this.apellidoPaterno;
}

@Column(name = "regimen_fiscal", length = 100)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public RegimenFiscal getRegimenFiscal() {
    return this.regimenFiscal;
}

public void setRegimenFiscal(RegimenFiscal regimenFiscal) {
    this.regimenFiscal = regimenFiscal;
}

@Column(name = "nacionalidad", length = 100)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
public Nacionalidad getNacionalidad() {
    return this.nacionalidad;
}

public void setNacionalidad(Nacionalidad nacionalidad) {
    this.nacionalidad = nacionalidad;
}

@Column(name = "rfc", length = 13)
public String getRfc() {
    return this.rfc;
}

public void setRfc(String rfc) {
    this.rfc = rfc;
}

@Column(name = "curp", length = 45)
public String getCurp() {
    return this.curp;
}

public void setCurp(String curp) {
    this.curp = curp;
}

@Column(name = "genero", length = 1)
@Convert(converter = GeneroConverter.class)
public Genero getGenero() {
    return this.genero;
}

public void setGenero(Genero genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "fecha_nacimiento", length = 10)
public Date getFechaNacimiento() {
    return this.fechaNacimiento;
}

public void setFechaNacimiento(Date fechaNacimiento) {
    this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
}

@Column(name = "es_cliente")
public Boolean isCliente() {
    return this.esCliente;
}

public void setIsCliente(Boolean esCliente) {
    this.esCliente = esCliente;
}

@Column(name = "es_contratante")
public Boolean esContratante() {
    return this.esContratante;
}

public void setEsContratante(Boolean esContratante) {
    this.esContratante = esContratante;
}

@Column(name = "es_pagador")
public Boolean isEsPagador() {
    return this.esPagador;
}

public void setEsPagador(Boolean esPagador) {
    this.esPagador = esPagador;
}

@Column(name = "es_monto_pagar")
public Boolean getEsMontoPagar() {
    return this.esMontoPagar;
}

public void setEsMontoPagar(Boolean esMontoPagar) {
    this.esMontoPagar = esMontoPagar;
}

@Column(name = "monto_pagar", precision = 16, scale = 4)
public BigDecimal getMontoPagar() {
    return this.montoPagar;
}

public void setMontoPagar(BigDecimal montoPagar) {
    this.montoPagar = montoPagar;
}

@Column(name = "es_porcentaje_pagar")
public Boolean getEsPorcentajePagar() {
    return this.esPorcentajePagar;
}

public void setEsPorcentajePagar(Boolean esPorcentajePagar) {
    this.esPorcentajePagar = esPorcentajePagar;
}

@Column(name = "porcentaje_pagar", length = 6)
public String getPorcentajePagar() {
    return this.porcentajePagar;
}

public void setPorcentajePagar(String porcentajePagar) {
    this.porcentajePagar = porcentajePagar;
}

public void setOrigenPersona(String origenPersona) {
    this.origenPersona = origenPersona;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "persona", targetEntity = ExpedientePersona.class, optional = true)
protected ExpedientePersona getExpedientePersona() {
    return this.expedientePersona;
}

protected void setExpedientePersona(ExpedientePersona expedientePersonas) {
    this.expedientePersona = expedientePersonas;
}

/**
 * @return parentesco
 */
@Column(name = "parentesco", length = 50)
public String getParentesco() {
    return parentesco;
}

/**
 * @param parentesco
 */
public void setParentesco(String parentesco) {
    this.parentesco = parentesco;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "persona", targetEntity = Cliente.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH })
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
public Cliente getCliente() {
    return this.cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

/**
 * @return si la persona esta relacionada al contratante y es una familiar este campo idnica que
 * parentesco tienen.
 */
@Transient
public Parentesco getTranParentesco() {
    return tranParentesco;
}

/**
 * @param tranParentesco
 */
public void setTranParentesco(Parentesco tranParentesco) {
    this.tranParentesco = tranParentesco;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "persona", targetEntity = Domicilio.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@OrderBy
protected List<Domicilio> getDomicilios() {
    return this.domicilios;
}

protected void setDomicilios(List<Domicilio> domicilios) {
    this.domicilios = domicilios;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "persona", targetEntity = Telefono.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@OrderBy
protected List<Telefono> getTelefonos() {
    return this.telefonos;
}

protected void setTelefonos(List<Telefono> telefonos) {
    this.telefonos = telefonos;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "persona", targetEntity = Correo.class, cascade = {
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@OrderBy
protected List<Correo> getCorreos() {
    return this.correos;
}

protected void setCorreos(List<Correo> correos) {
    this.correos = correos;
}

}
```

Comment: Please describe your issue in plain English or atleast show any error messages that you are encountering. This is not a debugging service, we are hear to help and learn from each other but posting code alone is hard to help you effectively, many of us charge people good money for that kind of service. Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hi, sorry about the incomplete message, I did not have time to complete the question. 
I already gave solution, it was a problem with the name of the getters, there were two similar getters